# Determining where in x-z plane, $f(z,t,x)$ is negative for all values of $0<t<\pi$

Tags: plotting, regions

I want to mark regions in $z - x$ plane in which, a know function,$f(x,z,t)$, is negative for all values of $0<t<\pi$.

How can I do that? I don't want to plot $f$ in $3D$. Could anyone help me?

The function f(t,x,z) is as below:

```
    f[x_ , z_ , t_ ] :=Re[0.125 (-21.2 + 
 Re[2 z Cos[2 t] - 
   2 z Cos[2 t]^2 + (2. E^(-I t) (E^(2 I t) (-8. - 3. x) z + 
        E^(12 I t) (-8. - 3. x) z + x z + E^(14 I t) x z + 
        E^(6 I t) (105.6 + 79.2 x - 8. z - 1. x z) + 
        E^(8 I t) (105.6 + 79.2 x - 8. z - 1. x z) + 
        E^(4 I t) (-79.2 x + 16. z + 3. x z) + 
        E^(10 I t) (-79.2 x + 16. z + 3. x z)) ((28.4 - 5. x + 
           0.25 x^2 + (-24.4 + 8. x - 0.125 x^2) Cos[
             2 t] + (-3. - 0.25 x) x Cos[4 t] + 
           0.125 x^2 Cos[6 t])^2)^(1/4))/(E^(2 I t) (-24. - 
         2. x) x + E^(10 I t) (-24. - 2. x) x + x^2 + 
      E^(12 I t) x^2 + E^(4 I t) (-195.2 + 64. x - 1. x^2) + 
      E^(8 I t) (-195.2 + 64. x - 1. x^2) + 
      E^(6 I t) (454.4 - 80. x + 4. x^2))])]
```

By the use of solution, I want to do the same thing when there are two functions which should be negative for all values of t:

```
g[x_ , z_ , t_ ] :=Re[0.125 (-21.2 + 
     Re[2 z Cos[2 t] - 
       2 z Cos[2 t]^2 + 2. E^(-I t) (E^(2 I t) (-8. - 3. x) z + 
            E^(12 I t) (-8. - 3. x) z + x z + E^(14 I t) x z + 
            E^(6 I t) (105.6 + 79.2 x - 8. z - 1. x z))]


max[x_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] :=NMaximize[{f[x, z, t], 0 <= t <= Pi}, t,Reals, AccuracyGoal -> 5,PrecisionGoal -> 5][[1]]

max[x_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] :=NMaximize[{g[x, z, t], 0 <= t <= Pi}, t,Reals, AccuracyGoal -> 5,PrecisionGoal -> 5][[1]]


RegionPlot[ max[x, z] <= 0 , {x, -10, 10 }, {z, -10, 10},"NumericalFunction"-> False ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
f[x_ , z_ , t_ ] :=Re[0.125 (-21.2 + 
 Re[2 z Cos[2 t] - 
   2 z Cos[2 t]^2 + (2. E^(-I t) (E^(2 I t) (-8. - 3. x) z + 
        E^(12 I t) (-8. - 3. x) z + x z + E^(14 I t) x z + 
        E^(6 I t) (105.6 + 79.2 x - 8. z - 1. x z) + 
        E^(8 I t) (105.6 + 79.2 x - 8. z - 1. x z) + 
        E^(4 I t) (-79.2 x + 16. z + 3. x z) + 
        E^(10 I t) (-79.2 x + 16. z + 3. x z)) ((28.4 - 5. x + 
           0.25 x^2 + (-24.4 + 8. x - 0.125 x^2) Cos[
             2 t] + (-3. - 0.25 x) x Cos[4 t] + 
           0.125 x^2 Cos[6 t])^2)^(1/4))/(E^(2 I t) (-24. - 
         2. x) x + E^(10 I t) (-24. - 2. x) x + x^2 + 
      E^(12 I t) x^2 + E^(4 I t) (-195.2 + 64. x - 1. x^2) + 
      E^(8 I t) (-195.2 + 64. x - 1. x^2) + 
      E^(6 I t) (454.4 - 80. x + 4. x^2))])]
```

it is possible to define the function

```
max[x_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] :=NMaximize[{f[x, z, t], 0 <= t <= Pi}, t,Reals, AccuracyGoal -> 5,PrecisionGoal -> 5][[1]]
```

which gives the maximum of f for given x,z.

Using RegionPlot the region f<0 can be calculated:

```
RegionPlot[ max[x, z] <= 0 , {x, -10, 10 }, {z, -10, 10},"NumericalFunction"-> False ]
```

[image]

Comment: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded. >>

Comment: Further output of NMaximize::cvdiv will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Comment: @ Wat Watson: ...but the result tells its own tale. Isn't it what you asked for?

Comment: Yes, of course it is. But I'm not sure about correctness of the result(because there are some errors)

Comment: Help of the warning NMaximize::cvdiv says `This message can sometimes be issued in cases when there is a finite optimum.` Your knowledge concerning f might help finding the right method.

Comment: What do you mean by right method?

Comment: By the way, it helped me too much, indeed :) Tnx

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing for more than one function? I mean, consider a case in which I want to find regions which both functions $f$ and $g$ should be negative for all values of $t$

Comment: I meant the right method to use with NMaximize. For example if your function has regions of constant max-value I wouldn't worry about the warning NMaximize gave. Otherwise you have to look for well adapted method.

Comment: Just use two conditions (f and g) inside RegionPlot!

Comment: Would you please chek what I have added to the question?

Comment: You have to define different max functions maxf,maxg: 
`RegionPlot[ maxf[x, z] <= 0&&maxg[x, z] <= 0 , {x, -10, 10 }, {z, -10, 10},"NumericalFunction"-> False ]`