# Lots of failed errors when using RegionPlot

Tags: plotting

By the help of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167282/determining-where-in-x-z-plane-fz-t-x-is-negative-for-all-values-of-0t-p) answer, I've written below code:

```
r = 2;
d = 1;
l = 1;
A = -1;
ro = 1;
v = 2;
g = 1;
f[e_, z_, t_] := 
 Re[-d + 1/2 z Cos[2 t] + 
   1/2 A z Cos[
     2 t]^2 + (E^(-3 I t) (1 + E^(2 I t)) (A + 2 E^(2 I t) + 
        A E^(4 I t)) z (-4 r + A e l ro + 2 (4 r + e l ro) Cos[2 t] + 
        A e l ro Cos[
          4 t]) ((Cos[t]^2 (2 r + e l ro + A e l ro Cos[2 t])^2 - 
         8 e l r ro (1 + A Cos[2 t]) Sin[t]^2)^2)^(
      1/4))/(16 (Cos[t]^2 (2 r + e l ro + A e l ro Cos[2 t])^2 - 
        8 e l r ro (1 + A Cos[2 t]) Sin[t]^2))]
gg[e_, z_, t_] := 
 Re[-d + 1/2 z Cos[2 t] + 
   1/2 A z Cos[
     2 t]^2 - ((E^(-3 I t) (1 + E^(2 I t)) (A + 2 E^(2 I t) + 
         A E^(4 I t)) z (-4 r + A e l ro + 2 (4 r + e l ro) Cos[2 t] +
          A e l ro Cos[
           4 t]) ((Cos[t]^2 (2 r + e l ro + A e l ro Cos[2 t])^2 - 
          8 e l r ro (1 + A Cos[2 t]) Sin[t]^2)^2)^(
       1/4))/(16 (Cos[t]^2 (2 r + e l ro + A e l ro Cos[2 t])^2 - 
         8 e l r ro (1 + A Cos[2 t]) Sin[t]^2)))]
h[e_, z_, t_] := 
 Re[-(Cos[t]^2 (2 r + e l ro + A e l ro Cos[2 t])^2 - 
     8 e l r ro (1 + A Cos[2 t]) Sin[t]^2)]
maxf[e_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 NMaximize[{f[e, z, t], 0 <= t <= Pi/2}, t, Reals, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 5][[1]]
maxg[e_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 NMaximize[{gg[e, z, t], 0 <= t <= Pi/2}, t, Reals, AccuracyGoal -> 5,
    PrecisionGoal -> 5][[1]]
maxh[e_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 NMaximize[{h[e, z, t], 0 <= t <= Pi/2}, t, Reals, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 5][[1]]
RegionPlot[
 maxf[e, z] <= 0 && maxg[e, z] <= 0 && maxh[e, z] <= 0, {e, -5, 
  5}, {z, -5, 6}, "NumericalFunction" -> False]
```

The problem is that, there are lots of errors, which I don't really know how to remove them. Could anyone help me? How can I remove the errors?

```
" Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded."
```

The function can not be unbounded. I don't know where does this error come from.

Comment: `The problem is that, there are lots of errors` one way would be to test each function on each own to make sure it works, before putting them all together.  debugging is hard, but testing each function first helps.

Comment: Testing each function alone, still there are some errors @Nasser